# Getting row/column name and integer-based index in a dataframe where a condition holds

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Given a dataframe `df` with a simple `Index` (not a `MultiIndex`) - that corresponds to a 2-D real matrix with names for rows and columns - and a boolean expression `e` over the elements in `df`, I would like to get:

- the name and the integer-based index of the rows
- the name and the integer-based index of the columns

of all the elements satisfying the expression `e`. The expression `e` is nothing special: I am interested in the rows/columns of the elements greater than a threshold.

After reading the documentation and plenty of questions and answers here, I wrote the code given below. It contains two solutions:

- one based on `numpy`. Basically, I extract the numbers from the dataframe and treat them as a `numpy` array. This solution seems reasonable: given the basic nature of the task, the code is simple enough.
- one based on methods provided by `pandas`. Even if `pandas` is designed for more complex scenarios than a simple matrix with numbers, this solution seems way too complex for what I am trying to accomplish.

##### set up the data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n_rows, n_cols, v = 4, 5, 3

rows = [ "r" + str(i) for i in range(n_rows) ]
columns = [ "c"  + str(i) for i in range(n_cols) ]
values = np.zeros( (n_rows, n_cols), dtype=int)

ii = np.random.randint(n_rows, size=(2,))
jj = np.random.randint(n_cols, size=(2,))

poss = zip(ii, jj)
for pos in poss:
    print(f"target set at {pos} -> ({rows[pos[0]]}, {columns[pos[1]]})")
    values[pos] = v + 1

print(" === values ===")
print(values)

df = pd.DataFrame(values, index=rows, columns=columns)
print(" === df === ")
print(df)
```

with output:

```
target set at (2, 4) -> (r2, c4)
target set at (1, 0) -> (r1, c0)
 === values ===
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [4 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 4]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
 === df === 
    c0  c1  c2  c3  c4
r0   0   0   0   0   0
r1   4   0   0   0   0
r2   0   0   0   0   4
r3   0   0   0   0   0
```

##### solution with `numpy`

```
print("\n === USING NUMPY ===")
data = df.to_numpy()
indexes = np.argwhere(data > v)
for ind in indexes:
    print(f"(numpy) target found at {ind} -> ({rows[ind[0]]}, {columns[ind[1]]})")
```

with output:

```
 === USING NUMPY ===
(numpy) target found at [1 0] -> (r1, c0)
(numpy) target found at [2 4] -> (r2, c4)
```

##### solution with `pandas`

```
print("\n === WITH PANDAS ===")

# select the rows with at least one column satisfying the condition
cond = (df > v).any(1)
df2 = df[cond]
print(df2, "\n")

# stack 
stacked = df2.stack()
print(stacked, "\n")

# filter (again!)
stacked2 = stacked.loc[stacked>v]
print("indexes in stacked:", stacked2.index.to_list(), "\n")

# get index (it is a MultiIndex at this point)
target_rows = [a for (a, _) in stacked2.index.to_list()]
target_cols = [b for (_, b) in stacked2.index.to_list()]

target_rows_idx = [df.index.get_loc(row_name) for row_name in target_rows]
target_cols_idx = [columns.index(col_name) for col_name in target_cols]

for pos in zip(target_rows_idx, target_cols_idx):
    print(f"(pandas) target found at {pos} -> ({rows[pos[0]]}, {columns[pos[1]]})")
```

with output:

```
 === WITH PANDAS ===
    c0  c1  c2  c3  c4
r1   4   0   0   0   0
r2   0   0   0   0   4 

r1  c0    4
    c1    0
    c2    0
    c3    0
    c4    0
r2  c0    0
    c1    0
    c2    0
    c3    0
    c4    4
dtype: int64 

indexes in stacked: [('r1', 'c0'), ('r2', 'c4')] 

(pandas) target found at (1, 0) -> (r1, c0)
(pandas) target found at (2, 4) -> (r2, c4)
```

Is there a simpler way to write the code using only `pandas`?

Answer (score 0):

Since [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) drops `NaN` values by default, we could mask out the values first *then* [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) (this avoids the need to filter twice). Then just grab the [`index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.index.html) and use [`get_loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) on both `index` and `columns` to convert the labels to integer values:

```
stacked = df[df > v].stack()
label_idx = stacked.index.tolist()
integer_idx = [(df.index.get_loc(r), df.columns.get_loc(c))
               for r, c in label_idx]

for i, j in zip(integer_idx, label_idx):
    print(f'(pandas 2) target found at {i} -> {j}')
```

Output:

```
(pandas 2) target found at (0, 0) -> ('r0', 'c0')
(pandas 2) target found at (1, 4) -> ('r1', 'c4')
```

`stacked`:

```
r0  c0    4.0
r1  c4    4.0
dtype: float64
```

`label_idx`:

```
[('r0', 'c0'), ('r1', 'c4')]
```

`integer_index`:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 4)]
```

---

Reproducible with:

```
np.random.seed(22)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `pd.Series.iteritems()`:

```
>>> [x for x, y in df.gt(3).stack().iteritems() if y]
[('r1', 'c3'), ('r2', 'c3')]
```

For index:

```
>>> [(df.index.get_loc(a), df.columns.get_loc(b)) for (a, b), y in df.gt(3).stack().iteritems() if y]
[(1, 3), (2, 3)]
>>>
```

---

`df` in this case:

```
>>> df
    c0  c1  c2  c3  c4
r0   0   0   0   0   0
r1   0   0   0   4   0
r2   0   0   0   4   0
r3   0   0   0   0   0
>>>
```